# Remove association for a file that begins with a '.' (no extension)

Tags: eclipse, windows-7-x64, file-extension

I have quickly(foolishly) tried to open an Eclipse '.project' file, and I accidentally registered it to open with Notepad.  How can I get the '.project' file to not be associated with any program.  There is no entry in the registry or 'assoc' command line list for '.project' or a blank file extension.  I have even tried [unassoc.exe](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/unassociate-file-types-windows-7-vista/), it seems to only simplify the process of looking through the registry, and deleting the key.  Yet there is no key, because the name is '.project' with out an extension.

Comment: Registered in where - Eclipse or Windows? The Windows associated doesn't mattter much as Eclipse never uses it.

Comment: That is a doozy of a problem! I (foolishly) replicated it on Win 7 (incorrectly) thinking it would be easy to fix. One difference in my case was that there WAS a registry entry for ".project" under FileExts (see the selected answer for https://superuser.com/questions/153465/always-use-this-program-to-open-these-files-is-grayed-out-why), but even after completely deleting that entry the problem remained. I also tried associating .project with EditPadLite, then deleted EditPadLite and the registry entry and rebooted, and the association still reverted to Notepad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated your problem on Windows 7, then solved it by removing all **.project** entries in the Windows Registry. Since there were no registry entries or file association for **.project** before creating the file association with Notepad the deletions didn't seem very risky.

After creating a file association with Notepad for **.project** and fooling around for a while the following eight Registry entries were created:

1. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.project
2. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes.project
3. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.project
4. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs.project
5. HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3639240256-3951415004-4078690541-1000\Software\Classes.project
6. HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3639240256-3951415004-4078690541-1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.project
7. HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3639240256-3951415004-4078690541-1000\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs.project
8. HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3639240256-3951415004-4078690541-1000_Classes.project

Once I had deleted only entry #1 above I got the "*Windows cannot open this file...*" prompt when trying to open a **.project** file, but there is no point in retaining any **.project** Registry entries if you are removing the file association. The usual caveats apply before messing with the Registry: use at own risk, backup the Registry first, take a checkpoint, etc...

Given that solution, I am baffled that you have no entries in the Registry for **.project** since that is definitely how Windows handles file associations. For example, see  this superuser question [How do you remove a default program association for file types in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7/49617#49617)

Can you try checking the Registry for **.project** entries one more time, especially in the locations provided above? I use **regedit** and that can be a bit flaky with searches if you don't refresh.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but there was no HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.project when I looked the first time.  But, as well, I was a little hesitant to mess with the registry.  I have had problems before, even after I exported it, and went back to an import.  But that was in  older version of Windows, so it may be better now.

This has done it, from what I can tell.

Thank You